How do I use the mouseup event to control a game in JavaScript?
I'm trying to make a game in HTML5 canvas. For this, I created this control module with this function that adds listeners for keyboard and mouse inputs. However, the mouseup event is not working/working as expected. When clicking with the mouse, the object starts moving, but when releasing the mouse, the object does not stop.
Sorry for not posting a fiddle. The complete project is here: Github and the working version is here: Github Pages.
export let
goLeft = false,
goRight = false,
doShoot = false;

export function addEventListeners() {
    // Adds listeners for the keys.

    //  On press:
    addEventListener('keydown', ({code}) => {
        switch (code) {
            case 'Numpad4': goLeft = true; break;
            case 'Numpad6': goRight = true; break;
            case 'Space': doShoot = true; break;
        }
    });

    //  On release:
    addEventListener('keyup', ({code}) => {
        switch (code) {
            case 'Numpad4': goLeft = false; break;
            case 'Numpad6': goRight = false; break;
            case 'Space': doShoot = false; break;
        }
    });

    // Adds listeners for the mouse:
    
    //  On press (right or left side of the canvas):
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ({offsetX}) => {
        (offsetX < canvas.width / 2) ? goLeft = true : goRight = true;
    });
    
    //  On release (any place the canvas):
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        goLeft = goRight = false;
    });
}


Can you add a debugger; to the callback of your keyup listener, just before switch (code) and let us know what its value is?

Also, please add a snippet to your question, as people will be unlikely to check out your project and test locally and in the future your project may be very different from how it is looking alike now, making it difficult for future visitors to understand the question.

The Github repository shows code that does not resemble the one you show here. Please do as @LajosArpad said and add the relevant and up-to-date code (the code that you already show as well as the one that uses the shown script, because the error might as well lie withing there).

Solved, I don't know how. I just moved the control method from the Game class to the controls module.
@Davi, Maybe it's because I made one more commit in the repository, but the controls module is exactly this, just with one additional method to assist in development.

Github timestamps show that you updated 1 hour ago, when I wrote my comment the timestamp showed an update that has been made 19 hours ago, hence my comment.
